# Jenkins to Github integration with Deploy Key results in an access denied

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I’m working to integrate Jenkins to a GitHub repo that I have to pull code, and run.  I’ve add a GitHub repository URL to a Source Code Management section in a Jenkins job that I have set up.  I’ve ssh’ed into the Jenkins server and generated a KeyPair.

I’ve added the generated Public Key to GitHub under the Deploy Keys (I also tried it under SSH key), and my Jenkins job still displays the error **“Failed to connect to repository : Command "/opt/{user}/git/bin/git ls-remote -h git@github.com:{project}/{repo}.git HEAD" returned status code 128:**

Is there a way to solve this issue? I’ve tried generating a new key pair, and playing around with the credentials used to access the GitHub repo, but I haven’t had any luck.

Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you added a credential with the private key on Jenkins and selected that as the credentials?

Comment: @Curious yes, I generated a private key on the Jenkins server, and this has generated in a id_rsa.projectname.  I have referenced this in Credentials option through Jenkins as "From a file on Jenkins master" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.projectname, and by selecting the option "From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh" . Is this the correct way to add the credential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the [JENKINS/SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin)

That will allow you to indicate, below the ssh URL of your GitHub repo (int he Jenkins job configuration page) which SSH key you are using for your credentials.