# Github url doesn't integrate with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins. When i try to integrate my github repo with jenkins it throws an error as attached in screenshot. I'm uisng Jenkins 2.121.3 on CentOs7. Even if i add the credentials i'm unable to connect. Please help me here.

Thanks in Advance !!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wOsH.png)

Comment: have you went through configuration as described here? https://jenkins.io/solutions/github/

Comment: hi, the github authentication plugin installation encountered error :( looks like i'm in deep trouble

Comment: GitHub Authentication 
Failure -

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

Comment: just guessing here but maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522017/jenkins-to-github-integration-with-deploy-key-results-in-an-access-denied?rq=1

Comment: NOPE, IT DIDN'T WORK :(